# How to access an object from an object nested function with this keyword?

Tags: javascript, object, this

I have this object:

```
popup_data = {
    club: {
        type: 'club',
        type_img: {
            header: 'CLUB HEADER',
            img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600',
            sub_header: 'CLUB SUB HEADER',
            content: 'TEXT',
            hotspot_position: [5, -1.5, 2.5]
        },
        hotspots_array: [
            {   id: () => this.club.type + '-' + 'type_img',
                position: () => this.club.type_img.hotspot_position,
            },
        ]   
    },
```

How to get `type` and `type_img.hotspot_position` from these nested functions

Comment: If you have more than 1 object, you can create a utility to bind the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use the var name, `popup_data`

```js
popup_data = {
    club: {
        type: 'club',
        type_img: {
            header: 'CLUB HEADER',
            img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600',
            sub_header: 'CLUB SUB HEADER',
            content: 'TEXT',
            hotspot_position: [5, -1.5, 2.5]
        },
        hotspots_array: [
            {   id: () => popup_data.club.type + '-' + 'type_img',
                position: () => popup_data.club.type_img.hotspot_position,
            },
        ]   
    },
```

Read [This](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp) and [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

> What is **this**? 
> In JavaScript, the `this` keyword refers to an **object**.
>
> **Which** object depends on how `this` is being invoked (used or called).
>
> The `this` keyword refers to different objects depending on how it is used:
>
> In an object method, `this` refers to the **object**. 
> Alone, `this` refers to the global **object**. 
> In a function, `this` refers to the **global object**. 
> In a function, in strict mode, `this` is **undefined**. 
> In an event, `this` refers to the **element** that received the event. 
> Methods like `call()`, `apply()`, and `bind()` can refer `this` to **any object**.

Comment: I have couple objects and can't i use just this.type?

Comment: no, but if this answer solves your issue, dont forget to mark this as the answer to your question, thank you

Comment: also see my edit, there are useful links

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by the variable name that you assign the entire object into.

```
popup_data = {
    club: {
        type: 'club',
        type_img: {
            header: 'CLUB HEADER',
            img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600',
            sub_header: 'CLUB SUB HEADER',
            content: 'TEXT',
            hotspot_position: [5, -1.5, 2.5]
        },
        hotspots_array: [
            {   id: () => popup_data.club.type + '-' + 'type_img',
                position: () => popup_data.club.type_img.hotspot_position,
            },
        ]   
    },
```

Since you are using ES6 arrow function, `this` will not work at all. And if you used normal function, `this` would be the object inside `hotspots_array`, not the entire object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one item, and want all those items to have access to the root, you can bind the function.  You will need to use none arrow functions here, as they don't have a `this`..

You can even extract your `id` and `position` function out of the object too, so that your not creating multiple instances of the exact same function.

eg..

```js
function id() {
  return this.club.type + '-' + 'type_img';
}

function position() {
  return this.club.type_img.hotspot_position;
}


const popup_data = {
  club: {
    type: 'club',
    type_img: {
       header: 'CLUB HEADER',
       img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600',
       sub_header: 'CLUB SUB HEADER',
       content: 'TEXT',
       hotspot_position: [5, -1.5, 2.5]
    },
    hotspots_array: [
       {   
         name: 'test',
         id, position
       }, {
         name: 'test2',
         id, position
       }
    ]   
   }  
};

const popup_data_2 = {
  club: {
    type: 'this is club 2',
    type_img: {
       hotspot_position: [5, -1.5, 2.5]
    },
    hotspots_array: [
       {   
         id, position
       }
    ]   
   }  
};
 
function bindFunctions(r, a) {
  Object.entries(a).map(([k, v]) => {
    const tp = typeof v;
    if (tp === 'function') {
       a[k] = v.bind(r);
    } else if (tp === 'object') {
       bindFunctions(r, v);
    }
  });
}
 
 bindFunctions(popup_data, popup_data);
 bindFunctions(popup_data_2, popup_data_2);
 
 console.log(popup_data.club.hotspots_array[0].id());
 console.log(popup_data.club.hotspots_array[0].position());
 console.log(popup_data_2.club.hotspots_array[0].id());
```

Another option, having a single root item can be restrictive.  If you wanted something more fancy I would create your Object using a function and use the power of closures.  The example below I've added another prop that then has access to it's array.

```js
function makeObject(data) {
    const root = data;
    for (const h of data.club.hotspots_array) {
       //now lets add our functions
       h.id = () => root.club.type + '-' + 'type_img';
       h.position = () => root.club.type_img.hotspot_position;
       h.array = data.club.hotspots_array;
    }
    return root;
 }
 
 const o1 = makeObject({
 club: {
    type: 'club',
    type_img: {
       header: 'CLUB HEADER',
       img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600',
       sub_header: 'CLUB SUB HEADER',
       content: 'TEXT',
       hotspot_position: [5, -1.5, 2.5]
    },
    hotspots_array: [
       {   
         name: 'test',
       }, {
         name: 'test2',
       }
    ]   
   }
 });
 
 console.log(o1.club.hotspots_array[0].id());
 console.log(o1.club.hotspots_array[0].position());
 console.log('array:' + o1.club.hotspots_array[0].array.length);
```